# Where can I get tutorials for Access Management for Tridion 2011 SP1 or the manual?

Tags: 2011, authorization

We have installed Tridion for our enterprise and as a Content Admin/Author, I need some tutorials on Access Management and also if possible a link to the Manual.

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to the Tridion Stack Exchange site.

You have done the right thing in asking about Tridion CME security and doing some research before diving in.  **Tridion security is very flexible and powerful, but this does mean that you can easily tie yourself up in knots if you do not plan properly!**

The main thing to be aware of is that it is focused around `Users`, `Groups`, `Rights` and `Permissions`.  If you set these up well at the start, **and test them thoroughly**, then the security set up will serve you well.  If you try to cut corners or plan to 'come back and fix it later', then it can cause you a world of pain.

As well as looking through the security section of the [online documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=permission&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1369031500524&currentQuery=permission&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_2D8E37DC58EC4D98ABDFA8D1287E162B&query=&scope=&filename=CMIM_Security.xml&docid=concept_2D8E37DC58EC4D98ABDFA8D1287E162B&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=) (login required), **I would strongly recommend that you read Alvin's [SDL Tridion CME Authorization](http://www.createandbreak.net/2012/07/sdl-tridion-authorization.html) blog post** and and browse over [the 'authorization' tagged questions](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authorization) on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to explore below links (Requires Login)

[SDL Tridion Online Documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/ui.xql?c=t&action=html&resource=publist_home.html)

Releted links are below for Access Management:

[SDL Tridion Online Documentation - Setting rights](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=Groups&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1369031402850&currentQuery=Groups&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_EDDF7FE597C540DC9B1677A3045964B7&query=Groups&scope=&filename=Security_Rights.xml&docid=task_EDDF7FE597C540DC9B1677A3045964B7&inner_id=&tid=4572b649-dd7b-4f7e-a0f3-6ab58e0408ef&addHistory=true&resource=)

[SDL Tridion Online Documentation - User and group rights and permissions](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US&action=search&query=permission&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1369031500524&currentQuery=permission&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_2D8E37DC58EC4D98ABDFA8D1287E162B&query=&scope=&filename=CMIM_Security.xml&docid=concept_2D8E37DC58EC4D98ABDFA8D1287E162B&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=)